# C++ assignment side-effect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, tuples

While trying to ensure ascending order of two variables, I've encountered strange anomaly in Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler that can be illustrated by the following code snippet

```
    double x1 = 2;
    double x2 = 1;
    std::tie(x1, x2) = std::minmax(x1, x2);
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ",   x2 = " << x2 << "\n";
```

one would expect that x1 is 1 and x2 is 2. But they are not. Instead

```
    //output:
    //x1 = 1,   x2 = 1
```

Is there any good explanation, just to be sure not to fall into similar trap again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::minmax` returns its arguments back by reference.  What happens with your statement is, first `x1` gets assigned the value of `x2`, which is 1.  Then, `x2` gets assigned the value of `x1`, which was 2, but is now 1.

If you were to inline everything, it might look something like this:

```
// using pointers because references can't be rebound
double *less, *greater;

if (x1 <= x2)
{
    less = &x1;
    greater = &x2;
}
else
{
    // in your case, this is the branch taken
    less = &x2;
    greater = &x1;
}

x1 = *less;       // less points to x2, so now both x1 and x2 = 1
x2 = *greater;    // greater points to x1, and x1 = 1, so this assignment is redundant
```

I think part of your confusion comes from thinking (or hoping) that the assignments would happen simultaneously, but they don't. When you assign a `tuple` or a `pair`, the sub-objects are assigned in order, from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`std::minmax()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) accepts two *references* and returns a pair of *references*. In particular, in your case it will return a pair where the first element is a reference to `x2`, and the second element is a reference to `x1`.

On the left side of the assignment, on the other hand, you have:

```
std::tie(x1, x2)
```

Which also creates a pair of references (ok, a tuple of two references actually, but that doesn't matter), but this time the first element of the pair is a reference to `x1`, while the second element is a reference to `x2`.

Then, you assign the pair returned by `std::minmax()` to the pair returned by `std::tie`, which means that `x1` gets assigned the value of `x2` (which is `1`) first; *after that*, `x2` gets assigned the *new* value of `x1` (once again, that's because `std::minmax()` returned a pair of references, so the second element of that pair "sees" the side-effect of the assignment to `x1`), which is now `1`.

This should explain the output.